# Image Hover Overlay combined Text Hover Overlay

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have an image where when you hover over it, an overlay appears, but because I've also added texts as well, the overlay doesn't appear when I hover over the texts too.

The issue is: I want the text to also display the overlay not only the image. If you click the image and the texts, it should redirect you to another url.

I thought about making the text into a separate css and call out another overlay but that'll make the image appear even darker, and quite possibly unnecessary extra overlays and text overlaps.

HTML

```
<div class="item-masonry">
  <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
  <div class="posts">
    <p><h2>Title</h2></p>
    <p><h2>Date</h2></p>
    <p><h3>Excerpt</3></p>
  </div>
    <img src=""/>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
  </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.posts {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 5px;
  line-break: strict;
  color: white;
}

.overlay:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.overlay:hover:after {
  opacity:1;
}
```

Here's one of an example I want the hover effect to be: https://www.vogue.co.jp/

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add overlay class to parent to make it work

```
<div class="js-masonry">
    <?php if( have_posts() ): while( have_posts() ): the_post();?>
        <div class="item-masonry overlay"> /*added overlay class here*/
            <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
            <div class="posts">
                <p><h2>Title</h2></p>
                <p><h2>Date</h2></p>
                <p><h3>Excerpt</3></p>
            </div>
                <img src="dummyurl"/>
                <div class=""></div>
            </a>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; else: endif;?>
</div>
```